# Limit the collections shown to users connecting to TFS

Tags: security, tfs

When a user is connecting to a TFS address through visual studio team explorer, they enter the TFS address and after login they can see all collections and all team projects under those collections.

Is there a way to tell TFS which users can see which collections when connecting to the server so that way not everyone can see everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is not a member of any of the groups in any of the projects in a Collection then they should not see the Collection listed.

Try removing a user from all the Projects in the Collections you don't want them to see, and they should not be listed.

Comment: all users are part of the global VALIDUSERS group, and each collection has that group apart of it so thus every user can see every collection. How do I change this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove VALIDUSERS from whatever collection access you've given it and add each user at the project level as contributors